# How to reduce generating files of SQL "Alter Table/Partition Concatenate" in Hive?

Tags: merge, hive, concatenation, apache-tez

Hive version: 1.2.1

Configuration:

```
set hive.execution.engine=tez;
set hive.merge.mapredfiles=true;
set hive.merge.smallfiles.avgsize=256000000;
set hive.merge.tezfiles=true;
```

HQL:

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name` PARTITION (partion_name1 = 'val1', partion_name2='val2', partion_name3='val3', partion_name4='val4') CONCATENATE;
```

I use the HQL to merge files of specific table / partition. However, after execution there are still many files in output directory; and their size are far less than 256000000. So how to decrease the number of output files.

BTW, use MapReduce instead of Tez also didn't work.

Comment: can you post the table DDL ?

Answer (score -2):

You may set your reducer number to 1 then, it would only create one output file.

You may do it with the following;

```
set mapred.reduce.tasks=1
```

Comment: Please check the comment: BTW, use MapReduce instead of Tez also didn't work. So he may use MapReduce as well if he wants to. In addition, you may use the configuration above also for Tez.

Comment: I can also ensure you that it does solve the issue. Maybe tez is slightly different story but it does work for MapReduce and it is what user asked.

Comment: I have tried it rigth now and the result is that I have 25 files. Moreover the triggered MapReduce job is a map-only job. Maybe you are using a different Hive version. I'm using Hive 1.2.1 and the files are ORC. And in these conditions, your solution doesn't work.

Comment: Well, can you please try to set the mappers to 1 ?

Comment: Well,  then i am out of ideas sorry for that.

Comment: this does not work

Answer (score -2):

Maybe u can try `insert overwrite table ... partition ( ... ) select * from ...`

This one can use the merge setting for tezfiles.